# Algorithm Notation on Journal

Tags: algorithm, border, notation

I am having trouble read algorithm in a journal. It's about border following by Suzuki and Abe. I just wondering, what is the meaning of left arrow (<-) on picture below, (i2,j2) <- (i,j-1).

I'm will be very glad if you can help explain this algorithm works.

[image: notation problem]

Comment: It's assignment, assign values i to i_2 and j-1 to j_2

Comment: Oh ok. Thanks. Hmm.. and how about i2,j2, is it the same as coordinate i+2 and j + 2 ?

Comment: i_2,j_2 are new variables, I don't know how and where they are defined.